# why click event is fired first called by onclick on element, rather than $(document).on('click')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application I have alot of anchor tags and buttons and most of them have event called by onclick on the element.

what I want is to call a function before any other functions are called.

**html**

```
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="add()">
<input type="button" value="sub" onclick="sub()">
<input type="button" value="div" onclick="div()">
```

**js**

```
function add(){
alert("add");
}
function sub(){
alert("sub");
}
function div(){
alert("div");
}

$(document).on("click","input[type=button]",function(){
alert("bye");
});
```

here is the fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmbcgz5y/9/)

I supposed that

```
$(document).on("click","input[type=button]",function(){
....
});
```

will be called first so that I can process something before

```
function show(){
    alert("hi");
    }
```

is called , but that is not true.
what should do to accomplish this.

I want to call **a** function on all anchor tags and buttons, even before the

**onclick="show()"**

> Update

I have updated the fiddle

**P.S**

each element have its own function to call , but the function in $(document) is same which i want to call on all element filtered by. 
I have suggestions that why not to make a function having logic of $(document) I have and call it on all functions called by elements i.e add(),sub(),div().
But ans is no I can not , because it is just a demo my real application is quit large and cannot figure each function and call other function. thats why I want an alternative.

Comment: more explain your question?it is not clear

Comment: your fiddle should be http://jsfiddle.net/qmbcgz5y/5/

Comment: @talsibony yes I made changes

Comment: Why not remove the `onclick` and put the `show()` inside the jQuery click handler?

Comment: the onclick attr on the element will be first because it direct event on the element and when you attached the event to the document it first trigger on the document and then it check if it matches the ID you defined

Comment: This is the correct behavior, as `onclick` event, first will be triggered from `button` element when clicked and corresponding registered function `show()` will be called. As event has this behavior of bubbling up, until you manually stop propagation, It will be handled later on `$(document)` filtered with `input[type=button]` by calling anonymous callback...

Comment: there are 2 ways which both are messy you can check in your show function if other events are setup on the element and trigger them first the second will be to set the onclick function in timout

Comment: @ShaunakD because each element have its own function to call , but the function in `$(document)` is same which i want to call on all element filtered by.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar i understand that it is the right behavior, but is there any way to tackle it.

Comment: @10sw33 If you want to know the reason why this is happening then its simple. Since you have written your onclick in the html when the button is clicked the browser searches for the function that is called which is the show(). After the show function is executed then the the click event is registered in the dom. This is why you get the hi alert at first.

Comment: @10sw33 Does this suits your requirement  http://jsfiddle.net/qmbcgz5y/10/ ?

Comment: @10sw33 see my answer this is the one of the less ugly way you can do it... good question though when you getting deeper and deeper to JS you ask these kind of questions...

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar yes this is the behavior I want, but problem is that I have hundreds of buttons , and changing each of them would be quit messy and most **Risky** at this level.

Comment: @10sw33 And each of those hundreds of buttons have different callback functions?

Comment: @talsibony ahaan!! a nice trick :) I didn't know about that before :) thanks for sharing its something new I learned :)

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar exactly !!

Comment: @10sw33 http://jsfiddle.net/qmbcgz5y/11/ see my answer and look for the second solution I think this is the best way you can do it without messing in each function and you avoiding timeout that will cause delays also you are using one click event and not 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onclick attr will be called first because its direct event on the element
this is how it is but you can make some manipulations on the events from the function itself
 here is a way you can achieve what you want but as I said in my comment is a bit messy:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app>
  <head>      
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a id="click" onclick="show(this);">c</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function show(t){
    events = $._data(document, 'events');
    events.click[0].handler();
    alert("hi");
    $(document).off("click","#click");
}

$(document).on("click","#click",function(){
  alert("bye");
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

basicly what you do here is to call other handlers before you execute your onclick function logic on in other words you call other handlers from the onclick this code works but you should use some filters for the events you are looking for and run in a loop on each event

another way you can do it you can save the onclick value and attached it in the your own event and then remove the onclick attr val:

http://jsfiddle.net/qmbcgz5y/11/

```
function add(){
alert("add");
}
function sub(){
alert("sub");
}
function div(){
alert("div");
}
function firstfunction(){alert('first func');}

    $(function(){
        $("input[type=button]").each(function(){
          var onclickfunc = $(this).attr('onclick');
          $(this).attr('onclick','');
          $(this).on('click',function(){
           firstfunction();
           eval(onclickfunc);
         });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple solution by calling 2 methods on onclick() event as given below:

```js
function show(){
alert("hi");
}

function first(){
alert("bye");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="click" onclick="first();show();">Click Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**javascript code**

```
function show() {
  function_two(); // considering the next alert, I figured you wanted to call function_two first
  alert("hi");
}

function function_two() {
  alert("bye");
}
```

**html code**

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="show()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have all functionality on the same event?

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="click" >
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click","input[type=button]",function(){
   // call first function
   callToFirstFunction();

   // continue here with other code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into capturing vs. bubbling event handling, which is very well explained [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

If you don't care about IE <= 8, you can just assign the event handler on the document to execute in the capturing phase. However, you must assign the event handler using the `addEventListener()` method, as this cannot be done through jQuery.

```
// third parameter must be true to set event to capturing phase
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // get the real target of the click event
    $target = $(event.target);

    // if it was a button, do your work
    if ($target.is('input[type="button"]')) {
        alert("bye");
    }
}, true);
```

If you do need to support IE <= 8, then one of these other workarounds will be needed.